# field integrity exception: unknown (scheduling not enabled on product):

Tags: apex, opportunity-lineitem, product, schedule, opp-lineitemschedule

I have written a trigger, when **`opportunityLineItem`** is inserted the quantity gets scheduled meaning **`opportunityLineItemSchedule`** are also gets inserted.

Now to re-enter the quantity I have cloned the edit page of **`opportunityLineItem`** where user can re-enter the quantity and schedules can be inserted according to the changed quantity.

But error is coming like

> field integrity exception: unknown (scheduling not enabled on product):

Answer (score 2):

You need to enable the Schedules to use that functionality.

You can enable it by going to the following from Setup menu: Customize->Products->Product Schedules Settings. You will have an option to enable schedules separately for quantity and revenue.

Comment: thanks for the reply @vladykx... problem has been solved. At the back end in trigger I was taking Revenue instead of Quantity.